# How to pivot without aggregation in python or sql

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, pivot

I want to pivot a table such that each row in the type column is now its own row. Each metric is then a row and the values are the intersection of the metric and type. There are a variable number of types and metrics.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7gPK.png). I do not want to alter the values in any way with aggregations. Any help with python or sql would be greatly appreciated!

I tried the pivoting function in SQL however I do not want to aggregate any values

Python example:
d = {'Type': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],
'Metric': ['q rate','w rate','e rate','r rate', 't rate','q rate','w rate','e rate','r rate', 't rate'],
'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7,6,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Type, Metric, Value
FROM `table`
)
PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR Type in ('List_of_types'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you you have a [pivot](/questions/tagged/pivot) tag, here is a proposition with [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .pivot(index="Metric", columns="Type")
          .reset_index()
          .droplevel(0, axis=1)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       )
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

           a  b
0  e rate  3  7
1  q rate  1  9
2  r rate  4  6
3  t rate  5  5
4  w rate  2  8
```

*Update :*

To get the second desired output, use this :

```
out = (
        df
          .pivot(index="Metric", columns="Type")
          .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
       )
​
print(out)

       Value1    Value2   
Type        a  b      a  b
e rate      3  7      7  3
q rate      1  9      9  5
r rate      4  6      6  2
t rate      5  5      5  1
w rate      2  8      8  4
```

Comment: You screenshot says otherwise (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7gPK.png, right corner). Can you show your _new_ expected output ?

Comment: Is there a way to add additional columns with the column name? The pivot works however the column names are not maintained. For example if I add another column "Value 2",  I would like the heading to be "a" then value 1, value 2 then "b", value 1, value 2. In other words the header would be two rows with Value 1 and Value 2 as subsets of "a" and "b".

Comment: You need to add your _new_ expected output to your question (as you did before). Otherwise, you may need to open a new question.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! here is the intended outcome https://imgur.com/a/LmwXOh5

Comment: Thanks again I really appreciate your help! Last question, would it be possible to flip the order of Type and Value such that Value1 and Value2 are a subset of the type like in the imgur image? https://imgur.com/a/LmwXOh5

Comment: No worries, add this line right before the print : `out.columns = out.columns.swaplevel(1, 0)`. If it still not give you the expected, let me check that later, AFK now ;)